# Heroku after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've already deployed my app to `Heroku`. It gave me the url as a result and said it was already deployed, when I check out the link it given me I got the Welcome to Rails screen. i've already deleted the `public/index.htm`, but i'm not sure on how to setup routes in `config/routes.rb`

btw, I'm certain that I've removed public/index.htm but when I visited the url again it shows the Welcome to Rails. I even check the directory and searches for `index.htm` were also 0. what could've happened?

Comment: have you run your database migrations? Does your routes.rb have a root_to route Perhaps showing the heroku logs would be good as well.

Comment: i don't have database for my app, it's just a simple app

Comment: What are the contents of your config/routes.rb?

Comment: what does the output of `git status` show?

Comment: @AlthafHamez `ConnectFour::Application.routes.draw do root :to => 'welcome#index' end`

Comment: @JohnBeynon `# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    public/index.html
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")`

Comment: Does your app work in development? Is it only broken on Heroku?

Comment: my app is done, i've already deployed it in heroku and it gave me the Welcome to Rails screen, i just don't know how to navigate the url so that when i visit it i can see my app.
i've tried creating a new controller(not sure if this was a good thing to do, cause there's already the `application_controller` which i think Aptana made when i deployed it using its wizard) `rails generate home index` and change `routes.rb` contents to `ConnectFour::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home/index" root :to => 'home_controller#index' end`

Comment: @yano, please see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already deleted `public/index.html`, then you'll need to create a *valid* root route. Replace `route to: 'home_controller#index'` with the following:

```
# config/routes.rb
root to: 'home#index'
```

Note that the word *controller* is **not included** in the `controller#action` notation. Hence, `home#index` *is valid*, but `home_controller#index` *is not*.

Once you've done this, commit your changes to version control and redeploy to Heroku.

Comment: this is what i put in routes.rb ` root :to => 'application_controller#index'` though i'm not sure what to put to application.html.erb

Comment: it says that the page doesn't exists

Comment: What is the _precise_ error you're receiving? Try copy and pasting it.

Comment: when i try to reload the page it says `You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.` is that what you're asking?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You need to modify your root route to read `root to: 'home#index'`.

Comment: thanks, i think i understand now how this thing works.. last question though, does the source code should be in index.htm.erb overwriting its default content so that when i visit the page it the main app is executed?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking whether you should be replacing the content of `public/index.html`. The answer is __no__, you should be __deleting__ this file altogether. If present, `public/index.html` will prevent your project's route route from being mapped to.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful in answering your question (as several other users apparently did), would you kindly consider accepting it as correct?

Comment: no, i've already deleted `public/index.html`. it's the content of `view/index.htm.erb` bec this is what is being displayed on the page

Comment: thanks for the help.. i think i solved my last question, i just need to put this `<%= javascript_include_tag "welcome" %>`  into `index.htm.erb` including all other linked scripts and css, right? then commit again and redeploy .. thanks a bunch ..!

Comment: Yep, put it within `<head></head>` tags and it should all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

From your `git status` output:

```
# On branch master 
# Changes not staged for commit: 
# (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be     committed) 
# (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory) 
# 
# deleted: public/index.html 
# no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So whilst you have indeed deleted public/index.html from the working tree you haven't deleted the file in git.

To do this do, if you do `git add -A` to stage the file for removal and then do a `git commit -m "Removing file"` before repushing to Heroku to commit the changed.

Alternatively, a more shorter way in one line is to do `git commit -am "Removing file"` which would stage any deleted files, stage any updated files and commit then in one go.